# Compact Set Question Involving a Finite Covering of Open Sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

A little background to this question before I state it:  we are currently in the "basic topology" chapter of my introductory real analysis course, and one of the homework problems this week has me confused.  It is at the end of the section regarding compact sets.  The book used is *Foundations of Analysis* by Krantz.

Now to the question...

**2.** Let $K$ be a compact set.  Let $\mathcal{U}= \{ U_j\}_{j=1}^k$  be a finite covering of $K$ by open sets.  Show that there is a $\delta>0$ so that, if $x$ is any point of $K$, then the disc or interval of center $x$ and radius $\delta$ lies entirely in one of the $U_j$.

After looking around the web for a bit, I discovered that my text doesn't define a compact set as I've seen it written elsewhere ([example](http://math.gmu.edu/~dwalnut/lec03.pdf) I found from George Mason University, see **Definition 1**).  More specifically, my text mentions nothing about what a *covering* is, of any kind. I could be wrong, but I feel that understanding what the finite covering $\mathcal{U}$ of "open sets" means is crucial to this problem.  As always, I'm not looking for the entire solution here, but rather some guidance to help me get there.  In particular, my questions (that I think will help me answer this) here are:

1. In respect to this question, what is a finite covering of $K$ by open sets, and what information does that provide in solving the problem?
2. For the second bit, how does one go about showing that there is some arbitrary $\delta$ such that the interval $(x-\delta,x+\delta)$ lies entirely in one of the $U_j$'s?

This problem has not only stumped me, but my instructor and classmates as well.  I feel that perhaps there is way to approach this problem that makes it out to be less difficult than it appears to be.  According to the author's structure, the "earlier" problems in each exercise section are the simpler ones, and the last few problems are the challenge problems, and this is the second exercise of eleven total.

Comment: What is your book's definition of a compact set?

Comment: Sorry, I probably should have mentioned that!  My book states that "a set $S\subset R$ is called compact if every sequence in $S$ has a subsequence that converges to an element of $S$."

Comment: A cover of set $X $, is a set of sets $\{U_{\alpha}\}$ so that $X \subset \cup_{\alpha} U_{\alpha} $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. A finite covereing of $K$ by open sets is, as stated, a collection $\mathcal U$ of finitely many (here: $k$) open sets $U_1,\ldots, U_k$, and such that $K\subseteq \bigcup_{k=1}^nU_i$.
2. Note that for all $x\in K$, you can find at least one $i=i(x)$ with $x\in U_i$, and by openness of $U_i$ some $r=r(x)$ such that the open ball $B_{r(x)}(x)$ of radius $r$ around $x$ is fully contained in $U_i$. As we can do so for all $x\in K$, we find that $$K\subseteq\bigcup_{x\in K}B_{r(x)}(x) $$
   Now use that every open cover of a compact has a finite subcover.

Comment: Except that's not his definition of compact.

Comment: From the list of exercises from the same text. Does this question have the same solution to the one OP has posted? "Let $K$ be a compact set and let $U$ be an open set that contains $K$. Prove that there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that, if $k\in K$, then the interval $(k-\epsilon, k+\epsilon)$ is contained in $U$." It seems like it is the same problem to me.